# dynamically formatting axis values

Tags: iccube-reporting

We have a filter, where the user can choose a measure, which we then show in a linechart. The measures to choose have different format_strings ('#,##0 €', '0.00', 'percent'). How can we set the format_string of the vertical axis matching the format_string of the chosen measure?

Unfortunately 'format_string' is not accessible as property of the measure (so [measures].[count sales].properties("format_string") doesn't work).

We tried to find something in 'icCube Serial' as well as in 'Google Generic Chart' without success.

Comment: Hi, it's currently not possible unless you add some javascript. We will keep this in mind for the roadmap. If it's important please contact support @ iccube

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We will check out the Javascript solution.